# IE11 Enterprise Mode not being enabled when page opened in popup page without toolbars or address bar

Tags: popupwindow, internet-explorer-11

we have a Ticketing system at work and it needs to run in Enterprise mode.

works great until it creaes a popup window that has no toolbar/address bar/status bar etc...
http://remedyweb/arsys/forms/removed_for_privacy/ITWRS+-+Generic+Transport/New/?cacheid=9615d0a9&format=html

the base address "remedyweb" is in my enterprise site list and works for all regular windowed browsing. but the popup fails.

if i open dev tools (F12) then change it to enterprise mode, it works. I'd post the image but don't have enough rep points.

Any ideas would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can enable enterprise mode by default for every site using a window registry entry.

And it will work for pop also. put the pop up URL in site list.

Comment: Could you elaborate or give a reference on how to create this window registry entry?

Comment: <rules version="1"> <emie> <domain exclude=”true”>domain_name <path exclude=”true”>/your_sub_paths</path> </domain> </emie> </rules> The above is a xml file.you have to create your own xml file like above example.And Save it somewhere in PC. And give that registry path in .. HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\EnterpriseMode.

Check that URL for more information ..
https://technet.microsoft.com/library/dn640699.aspx